# Android: in-app product ID

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, billing

How my in-app product ID should look like?
If my application ID looks like *com.example.test*, then can I define product ID just as *item*? Or should it be *com.example.test.item*?

Comment: What do you mean by `product id`? What is it?  Is it to identify a code item or is a good that you are selling?

Comment: This is the product id, which I should define at page https://market.android.com/publish/Home#InAppEditorPlace:sub=ADD&p=com.example.app

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I've tested that.
Product ID should be unique within your application. So *item* can be used. Everywhere it will be reflected as *com.example.test:item*.

Comment: please tell me in an in app billing product how many maximum number of product ids are supported

Comment: @LA in app i had draf apk it's package name is com.sp.testinapp and in inapp purchse i had made product with name Purchse Pro Version now after save it's display name/id under Purchase Pro Version(proversion) so which i consider as my product id?

Answer (score 5):

To be clear, you use exactly what you typed when creating the product.

It could be "productname" or "com.company.app.productname" depending on what your typed in. See the image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NJs3.jpg